# Hibernate exception on 4.0 XSD

Tags: java, hibernate, xsd, schema, dtd

First time out of the box with Hibernate, and getting a bizarre error. I am using the `4.2.3 Final` version, and would *like* to use the 4.0 XSD schema, but will use the 3.0 DTD if that's what it takes to get it to work.

My driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate/cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration
            .getProperties());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
            .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry());
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    User user = new User("Dr.", "Sylvester", "McMonkey", "McBean", "IV");

    session.save(user);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

My `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, located in my project under `src/main/config/hibernate/cfg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://my-server:3306/my_db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myuser</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the stacktrace Eclipse is giving me:

```
Jul 27, 2013 9:10:08 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jul 27, 2013 9:10:08 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.3.Final}
Jul 27, 2013 9:10:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jul 27, 2013 9:10:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jul 27, 2013 9:10:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate/cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml
Jul 27, 2013 9:10:08 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate/cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2070)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    at com.apponomical.adaptors.datasource.HibernateDriver.main(HibernateDriver.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:387)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:321)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3080)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:899)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2067)
    ... 2 more
```

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator is not finding the schema.  The xsi:schemaLocation attribute tells it to look for schema document hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd in the same directory as the configuration document you're validating (.../src/main/config/hibernate/cfg).  Is that where you have it?

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate 4.x you should use the same DTD as 3.x as you can see by this [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6617), where the deprecation warning was removed.
Also the tutorials for 4.2 version use this, as you can see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html_single/files/hibernate-tutorials.zip).